# How to switch to another activity as well as change the fragment which is in that Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main_activity with 3 different Fragment and a `SlideActivity`. I could make transactions among 3 fragments successfully in my `MainActivity`.

Now I add 1 button in the `MainActivity` and it will open the `SlideActivity`. On the `SlideActivity`, there are 3 buttons in the navigation bar to switch to each different fragments which I already created.

The problem is when I click the list button in the navigation, an error comes out shows that

> No view found for id 0x7f080052 (com.example.learnfragment:id/fragment_container) for fragment fragment_main{e1acaf7 #0 id=0x7f080052}

It seems that it cannot find the `FrameLayout` ID by `R.id.` and I believe because the navigation buttons are in the `SlideActivity` and it cannot find the ID which is in the `MainActivity`.

But how should I do for switching back to the `MainActivity` as well as changing different fragment?

Here's the `navigation_slide_activity.xml`

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_slide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_slide"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_slide_drawer" />
```

The `Navigation_Slide_Activity.java`:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Navigate back to the Main Fragment
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new fragment_main());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

And the `main_activity.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="392dp"
    android:layout_height="496dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

Finally, the `MainActivity.java`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create Fragment
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
                R.id.fragment_container,
                new fragment_main()).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a `public static` variable in your `MainActivity`.

```
public static int FRAGMENT_TO_BE_LOADED = 0;
```

Now from the `SlideActivity`, set the variable to a number (e.g. 3, that is you want to move to the third fragment when you are returning to your `MainActivity`.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        MainActivity.FRAGMENT_TO_BE_LOADED = 3; 
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now in your `MainActivity`, you need to have an `onResume` function which will check the variable and load the fragment accordingly.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(FRAGMENT_TO_BE_LOADED == 1) loadFragment1();
    else if(FRAGMENT_TO_BE_LOADED == 2) loadFragment2();
    else if(FRAGMENT_TO_BE_LOADED == 3) loadFragment3();
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, and it works perfectly! Since I cannot get the id from other activity, I can set up a statue and use MainActivity to show the Fragment. It is very smart!

Comment: Add one more question. If I am using the Tab Activity and switch between different ViewPage which should display the Fragment located in the main activity. How should I do it since I cannot finish my current Fragment Activity.

Comment: Take a similar approach. Instead of `finish()` you may do the switching and update the index in the static variable like above. Then when you return from the `FragmentActivity`, the `onResume` function will pick the value and will load the correct activity.